# How to extrapolate my sample results to population

Tags: inference, sample, population

We have tested randomly selected bacteria ($k = 198$) for antibiotic resistance over a period of 3 years (total isolates $n = 444$) and observed $117$ resistant strains.

I would like to extrapolate my results to total isolates. I presume,
$$\hat{q} = \frac{117 \times 444}{198} = 262.$$

Is there any specific statistical method for this analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the selected bacteria must have been selected **randomly** to do any inference.

262 is indeed a good estimate of the resistant strains you would have in your population. 
But what you would like to get - I guess - is to know how accurate is this estimation. The simplest way to do that is to compute confidence interval.
The 95% confidence interval for your proportion would be (if your population was infinite) :
$$\hat{p}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n} }$$
In your case, this is different, as you study almost half of your population, you can pretend to have a **better estimate of your proportion** :

$$\hat{p}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n} \cdot \frac{N-n}{N-1}}$$

In your case you have $z_{\alpha/2}=1.96$, $N=444$, $n=198$, $\hat{p}=\frac{117}{198}$

If I typed it right [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.96*%28sqrt%28%28%28117%2F198%29*%281-117%2F198%29%2F117%29*%28%28444-198%29%2F443%29) gives $0.066$

This means that in your population $0.591-0.066<p<0.591+0.066$ which in turns mean that you are 95% confident that $444*(0.591-0.066)<Nresistant<444*(0.591+0.066)$

To wrap it up :
$$P(233.1<Nresistant<291.7)=95\%$$

Comment: Thanks for your kind help in attaining extrapolation with 95% Confidence interval.

Comment: I did understand that 0.591 is derived from 117/198. But I couldn't understand how to calculate Za/2 i.e., 1.96. Can I conclude my extrapolation as 262 (233.1 - 291.7) with 95% CI

Comment: $z_{\alpha/2}$ is a value which **only** depends of the size of your confidence interval $\alpha=0.95$. Mathematically you have $P(|Z|>z_{\alpha/2}=0.95)$ with Z following normalized gaussian distribution($Z \sim N(0,1)$). Unless I mistyped the formula in wolfram alpha, this is then the confidence interval you can use.